# MobaXtern - how to run bash shell script from within Moba's own bash terminal?

Tags: shell, mobaxterm

**Problem**: In Mobaxterm's bash console running commands in a shell script fail while the same command runs from the command line.

**observation**:
It seems that the bash running inside of the MobaXterm terminal inside windows is "enhanced" by some busybox wrapper as a result commands typed in the terminal are different from the same commands called from a script in the terminal...

**example:**
xargs supports the -I option on the command line, but if you save the same command in a shell script and execute it, it fails... it looks like xargs on ther prompt is a builtin command different from the file itself...

```
  27/05/2021   13:50.30   /home/mobaxterm  echo foo |xargs -I{} echo {}
foo                                                                                                                                                                                                     ✔

  27/05/2021   13:50.45   /home/mobaxterm  echo "echo foo |xargs -I{} echo {}">bar.sh
                                                                                                                                                                                                 ✔

  27/05/2021   13:51.17   /home/mobaxterm  chmod 755 bar.sh
                                                                                                                                                                                                 ✔

  27/05/2021   13:51.26   /home/mobaxterm  ./bar.sh
xargs: unknown option -- I
BusyBox v1.22.1 (2015-11-10 11:07:12    ) multi-call binary.

Usage: xargs [OPTIONS] [PROG ARGS]

Run PROG on every item given by stdin

        -p      Ask user whether to run each command
        -r      Don't run command if input is empty
        -0      Input is separated by NUL characters
        -t      Print the command on stderr before execution
        -e[STR] STR stops input processing
        -n N    Pass no more than N args to PROG
        -s N    Pass command line of no more than N bytes
        -x      Exit if size is exceeded

                                                                                                                                                                                                 ✘

  27/05/2021   13:51.33   /home/mobaxterm  m


  27/05/2021   13:42.57   /home/mobaxterm  xargs --version
xargs (GNU findutils) 4.6.0
Packaged by Cygwin (4.6.0-1)
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Eric B. Decker, James Youngman, and Kevin Dalley.
                                                                                                                                                                                                 ✔

  27/05/2021   13:43.17   /home/mobaxterm  which xargs
/bin/xargs
                                                                                                                                                                                                 ✔

  27/05/2021   13:43.23   /home/mobaxterm  /bin/xargs --version
xargs: unknown option -- version
BusyBox v1.22.1 (2015-11-10 11:07:12    ) multi-call binary.

Usage: xargs [OPTIONS] [PROG ARGS]

Run PROG on every item given by stdin

        -p      Ask user whether to run each command
        -r      Don't run command if input is empty
        -0      Input is separated by NUL characters
        -t      Print the command on stderr before execution
        -e[STR] STR stops input processing
        -n N    Pass no more than N args to PROG
        -s N    Pass command line of no more than N bytes
        -x      Exit if size is exceeded

                                                                                                                                                                                                 ✘

  27/05/2021   13:43.28   /home/mobaxterm 
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing that you've solved your problem since then, but since I had the same problem, I thought to post it here for others. I searched for xargs in the available packages for mobaxterm.

```
apt-get search xargs

- Found command "xargs" in package "findutils"

➤ You can install this package by using the following command:
apt-get install findutils


apt-get searchdesc xargs

- Found description "Utilities for finding files--find, xargs, locate, updatedb" in package "findutils"

➤ You can install this package by using the following command:
apt-get install findutils
```

After installing this, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

If it is indeed `bash`, and not some other thing, then the most probable explanation is that its PATH is set incorrectly and so it is picking up the "bad" versions of some binaries. To check what's the actual binary run by a command, use `which xargs`. If the binary is not what you expect, you need to fix your PATH. (Search the web if you don't know how.)

Another possibility is that there are functions/aliases shadowing the binaries. Use `command xargs ...` to force the shell to use a command.

Comment: indeed, it is an alias... 
it looks like mobaxterm runs a pseudo shell called "busybox" which includes a number of commands which are usually external programs as internal functions. including xargs apparently... 
now I need to figure out a way to have my shell scripts use these busybox internals???

Comment: @ffsb I told you, you can bypass the shell builtins using `command`.  Anyhow, I don't see why you're bothering to use `mobaxterm` in the first place.